# Given an unsorted array of integers, all two elements of the array that sum to the value x. You must use a stack or a queue

Tags: arrays, stack, queue, sum, pseudocode

I have thought about it over and over but I can't figure out how a Stack or a Queue would be of any use in this case. Note that the use of a stack or queue is required... Please help!

Edit: I forgot to mention what the output should look like. Here is sample output:

```
All 2-Elements adding to 100 in the array are: 
Indices 0 & 3 with values 20 & 80 
Indices 3 & 6 with values 80 & 20 
Indices 3 & 12 with values 80 & 20 
Indices 4 & 5 with values 30 & 70 
etc.
```

Comment: Then don't use a stack or queue. Your requirements are unrealistic.

Comment: It's a homework question. I've been stuck on it for days and it's due tonight :(

Comment: Does your instructor approve of plagiarizing solutions/ideas from the internet?

Comment: I'm not stealing someone else's work without permission, I'm asking for help. There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (not the most effective way to solve the problem in question, obviously; e.g. putting all elements into a hash, then iterating over that hash and checking for every a[i] if the hash contains x-a[i] is supposed to be faster)

(assumptions: stack supports 2 operations:

- push - adding elements on top of the stack
- top - getting the value of the element on top of the stack without removing it from the stack)

> ```
> a = input_array
>
> l = list // list of pairs
>
> s = stack
>
> for i from 0 to length(a)-2:
>
>   s.push(a[i])
>
>   for j from i+1 to length(a)-1:
>
>       if s.top + a[j]==x:
>
>           l.add(pair(s.top,a[j]))
>
> return l
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to pop the elements in the stack in the if/else for this to work?

Comment: they are pushed into the stack in the outer cycle. in the if-else you only check what's on top of the stack.